# Obtain faces in threejs based on distance to camera

Tags: three.js

I have a cube (six faces). I render three faces of a statically-positioned cube with material that have their transparent property set.

I want to retrieve the three closest faces to the camera, so that I can set their transparency/opacity.

If I programmatically rotate the cube in the render loop, how would I calculate the distance of each cube's face (`Face3`) from the camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At any moment, only one of the 2 opposite faces can be in the 'closest' group ... or in the group that are facing the camera, it is the same subset.

So, for a pair of opposite faces , take the normal of one of the faces, and calculate the dot product of this vector and the vector linking that face to the camera. If the dot product is positive, choose this face. Else, choose the opposite face.

And repeat for the remaining 2 pairs of faces.

Comment: An instance of `Face3` has a `normal` property I can access to get vector components. What property would I access to get the vector linking the face to the camera?

Comment: Subtract the position of any of the face vertices  from the camera position